# Angular Universal Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am getting the following error while adding the clientProject with angular universal. There is no further explanation. Can anyone help?
Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Comment: You don't have a call stack?

Comment: What do you mean by a call stack. For the error, its only that message. Nothing else.

Comment: Show some code.  It appears you are trying to call `some` method on an undefined array.

Comment: Which part of code would you like to view?

Comment: My app runs just fine.

Comment: What command did you run to have this error?

Comment: ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject projectName

Comment: can you help out on this. I am really stuck. @David

Comment: Iy mzy be because of your angular.json file. Post it, maybe somebody will figure it out. Otherwise, you can add angular universal manually, there are some blog posts out there describing how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this issue related to your routing module, if you have router options already in your routing module

Comment: This solved it, thanks. How do i define my router options now. It worked when i removed the extraoptions completely.

Comment: you just manually append your router options once library install, please mark it as answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody else is having a hard time with this too:

**Issue**

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [PROJECTNAME]
```

[image: Cannot read property some of undefined]

You need to remove your `RouterOptions` because Angular needs to modify that code as part of the automatic changes it does to your project when you add `@nguniversal/express-engine`.

**Resolution**

Change the following code in your `app-routing.module.ts` from:

```
const options: ExtraOptions = {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    urlUpdateStrategy: 'eager',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, options)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

to the following:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

then run the command again. It should have completed without errors this time and you will have the right project changes. **Now you can change your code back to its original state with your custom `RouterOptions`.**

[More info on this Github issue page](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1748)